# Issues With Directory Creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

### **SOLVED**

Thanks to @James, This issue was completely solved!

***Solution***
Creating a specific function to create directories, shown below:

```
# SETTINGS.PY
pathNAME = '../Location'
PathName2 = pathNAME + '/Location2'
# Define Functions
def make_dir(directoryName):
    if os.path.exists(directoryName):
        if os.path.isdir(directoryName):
            return False
    os.mkdir(directoryName)
    print(directoryName)
    return True
```

And then In The Main Script

```
import settings
settings.make_dir(settings.pathNAME)
settings.make_dir(settings.pathName2)
```

That is how you do it! Thanks for everyone who tried to help! And Extra Thanks to @James!!

**Original Post**

---

**VIDEO**

[The Video Showing All My Code, and the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3VBt1fMGd0&feature=youtu.be)

**Description**

Basically, I am attempting to create folders for my project if they do not exist, however, when I run the .py file that creates the folders, it only creates two of them, and then claims that all the files already exist. Even though in the file explorer they do not (They also do not exist in terminal when I do ls). I tried moving the variables into the same file, and, I tried getting rid of the if statements, I also tried doing the `os.mkdir()` & setting the existOk to true. I never get any errors

**Console Outputs**

*First Run (No Folders Exist)*

```
True  # Main Directory: It thinks the base directory already exists
False # Logs Directory: It knows that the other directories do not exist
False # Users Directory: ^
False # Inventory Directory: ^^
False # Stats Directory: ^^^
../FrozenDesert # It Created The Base Directory
../FrozenDesert/Users # It Created The Users Directory
```

*Second Run (Users & Main Directory Exist)*

```
True  # Main Directory: Knows it exists
True  # Logs Directory: Thinks it exists
True  # Users Directory: Knows it exists
True  # Inventory Directory: Thinks it exists
True  # Stats Directory: Thinks it exists
      # No Directories were created
```

**The Code**

*Login Directory (Irrelevant)*

```
#Imports
import time
import os
import settings


#  Request User Input
print('Welcome To The Frozen Desert. Would You Like To Register Or Sign In?')
print(" ")

while True:
    # Store User Input
    identity = raw_input("Login [L] / Register [R]: ")

    # Checks To See If The Answer Is Appropriate
    if identity.lower() not in ('l', 'r'):
        continue
    print(" ")
    break

#TODO: Make Te Login & Registration Functions Work

# Begins User Login
if identity.lower() == "l":
    print("Opening Login Pane")
    time.sleep(1)
    # Clears Screen
    i = 0
    while i <= 50:
        print(" ")
        i += 1

#Begins User Registration
if identity.lower() == "r":
    print("Opening Registration Pane")
    # Clears Screen
    i = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    while i <= 50:
        print(" ")
        i += 1
```

*Settings Directory (Variables)*

```
# Imports
import os


# Define Locations
pathBase = '../FrozenDesert'
pathUsers = pathBase + '/Users'
pathInventory = pathUsers + '/Inventory'
pathStats = pathUsers + '/Stats'
pathLogs = pathBase + '/Logs'
directoryMain = os.path.dirname(pathBase)
directoryUsers = os.path.dirname(pathUsers)
directoryUserStats = os.path.dirname(pathStats)
directoryUserInventory = os.path.dirname(pathInventory)
directoryLogs = os.path.dirname(pathLogs)
```

*Launch Management (Creates Directories And Stuff)*

```
# Imports
import os
import settings

# Create Directories
print(os.path.isdir(settings.directoryMain))
print(os.path.isdir(settings.directoryLogs))
print(os.path.isdir(settings.directoryUsers))
print(os.path.isdir(settings.directoryUserInventory))
print(os.path.isdir(settings.directoryUserStats))

# TODO: Make Evrything Below Work
# Main Directory
if not os.path.isdir(settings.directoryMain):
    print(settings.directoryMain)
    os.makedirs(settings.directoryMain)

# Users Directory
if not os.path.isdir(settings.directoryUsers):
    print(settings.directoryUsers)
    os.makedirs(settings.directoryUsers)

# Logs Directory
if not os.path.exists(settings.directoryLogs):
    print(settings.directoryLogs)
    os.makedirs(settings.directoryLogs)

# User-Stats Directory
if not os.path.isdir(settings.directoryUserStats):
    print(settings.directoryUserStats)
    os.makedirs(settings.directoryUserStats)

# User-Inventory Directory
if not os.path.isdir(settings.directoryUserInventory):
    print(settings.directoryUserInventory)
    os.makedirs(settings.directoryUserInventory)
```

Comment: It may be better to use `os.exist()` instead of `os.isdir()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os` to check if the path exists, if it does, check if it is a directory, otherwise make a new directory.

```
import os

def make_new_dir(d):
    if os.path.exists(d):
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            return False
    os.path.mkdir(d)
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this method with the path variables (NOT the directory variables) and it seems to work every time!!

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've had better luck with

```
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir)
```

If thats not working then its possible it could be the relative file paths you are using. You can try getting the full path at run time for the base path using something like

```
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Although I'm not fully positive of your directory structure, so it might need to be adjusted after getting the working directory.

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you :) EDIT: When Changing all my if not statements, and the part where I print if it exists, I see the same results. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: @2VeryIcey i've edited my with another potential issue. If you are appending files to the working directory then using a relative file path might cause issues. Can you try using a full path instead?